# Drupal: path for entire taxonomy vocabulary view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

What's the path to display all nodes belonging to a vocabulary ?

In other words, I want to display all terms at once. (I don't want to filter by term, just show all nodes tagged with any term of a vocabulary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by grabbing a copy of views and using an appropriate filter.  Heck, you can do it where the vid is part of the path, so it works for all of the vocabularies.  Hold on...

Yeah, I thought so.  Here's a view I made recently that does this - just copy/paste this into the view import.

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'vocabulary';
$view->description = 'Displays all nodes in a vocabulary';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'sticky' => array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'id' => 'sticky',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'sticky',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'created' => array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'granularity' => 'second',
    'id' => 'created',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'created',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array(
  'vid' => array(
    'default_action' => 'not found',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '%1',
    'breadcrumb' => '',
    'default_argument_type' => 'fixed',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'none',
    'validate_fail' => 'not found',
    'id' => 'vid',
    'table' => 'vocabulary',
    'field' => 'vid',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      '2' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
      '4' => 0,
      '5' => 0,
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_php' => '',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'blog' => 0,
      'poll' => 0,
      'faq' => 0,
      'forum' => 0,
      'event' => 0,
      'link' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
      'story' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      '1' => 0,
      '5' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
      '6' => 0,
      '4' => 0,
      '7' => 0,
      '8' => 0,
      '9' => 0,
      '10' => 0,
      '11' => 0,
      '12' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
    'validate_argument_node_flag_name' => '*relationship*',
    'validate_argument_node_flag_test' => 'flaggable',
    'validate_argument_node_flag_id_type' => 'id',
    'validate_argument_user_flag_name' => '*relationship*',
    'validate_argument_user_flag_test' => 'flaggable',
    'validate_argument_user_flag_id_type' => 'id',
    'validate_argument_php' => '',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'status' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => '1',
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'status',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'status',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('use_pager', '1');
$handler->override_option('row_plugin', 'node');
$handler->override_option('row_options', array(
  'relationship' => 'none',
  'build_mode' => 'teaser',
  'links' => 1,
  'comments' => 1,
));
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->override_option('path', 'vocabulary/%');
$handler->override_option('menu', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler->override_option('tab_options', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
```

Comment: thanks! One more thing: I already have customized the taxonomy view (I enabled the default one from Views). Should I manually make the same changes to your view to make them appearing the same, or is there a faster way ?

Comment: I'd just go in and make the same changes to this view.  It's not really _my_ view in anyway, it's just a quick example of how to display all nodes in a given vocabulary.  And if you like the answer, you should vote it up!  Gotta reach 1500 pts somehow. :)

Comment: ok then, I can just duplicate the view and filter that specific content-type and I have all nodes anyway. Right ? And ok, I will vote it :)